# Current measurement in LTSpice

Tags: ltspice, current-measurement, neutral

In LTSpice, measuring a current through passive elements (components) is very straightforward. Now I'd like to measure a current through a neutral wire where no element is connected to it. So can someone tell me how to measure the current through a wire with no element is connected in LTSpice?
Best regards!

Comment: Well, it is ugly, but: cut this wire and put a 1 nOhm resistor there.

Comment: Or you can use a 0V voltage source as a "current monitor".

Comment: Using a 0 V DC voltage source to plot the current is common practice.

Comment: I feel like I am missing something. If you have a wire in SPICE with no element connected to it, how can there be any current at all flowing through it? Where would the current come from, and where would it go?

Comment: As @ElliotAlderson points out, if there are no elements at *both sides* of a wire, then there is no current through that branch. The error log might also say something about a "warning: floating node". Unless you meant something else? Otherwise, Ste's answer will do.

Answer (score 7):

Hold down ALT while probing around and the current measurement symbol will appear on your mouse cursor as you hover over a wire.  This only works on simulation commands which utilize the Waveform Viewer (e.g. `.ac` or `.tran`), so doing an `.op` simulation will only work if you use it alongside a `.step param` with more than one step.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After reading Ste Kulov's answer I'll try to forget how much time I have wasted by not knowing this and also that if you hover over components, it plots the instantaneous power...

Just an addition if you use LTSpice under Wine/Linux: the window manager may intercept the ALT-Click. E. g. under Xfce you can disable "grab and move windows" under the Window Manager Tweaks (or *xfconf-query -c xfwm4 -p /general/easy_click -s none* at the command line).

If you user another window manager, you may search for: *"your window manager" disable alt-click*.

Comment: If only the help would mention it... :-) (not the Wine part)

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I will not argue that the Help does not work under Wine because I agree that the problem is indeed RTFM. ;-)

Comment: I have tried several times but while holding ALT and hover over the wire just only the voltage probe is accessible. I couldn't see the current probe yet with the mentioned method. NB. my simulation utilizes .tram 10m.

Comment: @Ady I've just checked with the old LTSpice IV and the feature also works. If you leave the cursor over a wire and press ALT, the cursor changes from the voltage probe to the current measurement. If you leave it over a component and press ALT, it changes to a thermometer. Maybe if you add more details to the question, like the OS you are using, somebody may offer another suggestion.

Comment: Thank you very much I got it now